# Exception on removing entity from databound DbSet in Entity Framework Core

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, data-binding, entity-framework-core

When removing an item from a `DbSet` to which I've bound a WPF control (using the `Local` property) I get:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: Collection Remove event must specify item position.

This happens regardless of whether I call `Remove` on the `LocalView` or on the `DbSet` directly. I'm using the Sqlite provider, if that makes any difference.

Some simple code to reproduce the problem:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

   public BloggingContext DB { get; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        DB = new BloggingContext();

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void AddButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DB.Blogs.Add(new Blog() { Url = "http://blogs.msdn.com/adonet" });
    }

    private void RemoveButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DB.Blogs.Remove(DB.Blogs.Local.First());
    }
}

public class BloggingContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Filename=data.db");
    }
}

public class Blog
{
    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }

    public List<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}

public class Post
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public Blog Blog { get; set; }
}
```

And the MainWindow XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="EfCoreRemoveBug.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:EfCoreRemoveBug"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <DockPanel>
        <Button Content="Add" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Click="AddButton_Click"/>
        <Button Content="Remove" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Click="RemoveButton_Click"/>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding DB.Blogs.Local, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}" DisplayMemberPath="Url"></ListBox>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: Where did you get `Local` property? I don't see such property in the latest released EF Core, are you using WIP dev builds?

Comment: I was following the getting started instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/full-dotnet/new-db) and [this property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbset-1#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_DbSet_1_Local), it looks like NuGet installed version 1.1.0